# Error while updating business network in CLI tutorial

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am following along the [Getting Started with Fabric Command Line](https://fabric-composer.github.io/tutorials/getting-started-cmd-line.html) and have run into a error I don't understand how to resolve.  Any ideas?

In the section entitled "Update the deployed business network" an exception is thrown.  The terminal output is below.  The command used:

```
composer network update --archiveFile digitalproperty-network@0.0.7.bna  --enrollId WebAppAdmin --enrollSecret DJY27pEnl16d
```

Note that the id is different from the tutorial as the 0.0.7 id was reported during the previous step while creating.  The output continued...

```
Deploying business network from archive digitalproperty-network@0.0.7.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: digitalproperty-network@0.0.7
    Description: Digital Property Network
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/mnjacobs/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
    at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/home/mnjacobs/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:158:8)
    at readCallback (/home/mnjacobs/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:217:12)
```

I've struggled to get the versions to match the tutorials - they seem inconsistent.  Notably, the node (v6.9.5) and nodejs (v6.10.1) versions differ even though node is a symbolic link to nodejs and I notice 6.9.5 is in the stack trace.  I'm not sure that difference is relevant to the problem.

Other version information:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5
- Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e (manually installed as auto
  install was down level)
- docker-compose version 1.12.0-rc2, build 08dc2a4

Answer (score 1):

I've seen exactly that error when Hyperledger Fabric isn't running. If `docker ps` doesn't show anything, run `npm run startHLF` in the *sample-applications/packages/getting-started* directory before trying again.